# Return mixed non-series items + next upcoming in series

Tags: mysql, database, performance, join, greatest-n-per-group

I'm looking for the best way to handle the following query. I have a table of items, some (but not all) of which are part of a series of items (one per day). The ones in a series are grouped by a shared series ID:

```
Table "items":
    id
    series_id (may be NULL)
    title
    date
    etc.
```

The difficulty arises when I sometimes only want to return the *next upcoming* instance of any items which are part of a series. Something like:

```
SELECT items.id, items.series_id, items.title, items.date
FROM items
LEFT JOIN
    items AS series_table
    ON series_table.series_id IS NOT NULL
      AND series_table.series_id=items.series_id
      AND series_table.date>=CURDATE()
WHERE items.date>=CURDATE()
GROUP BY
    items.id 
HAVING
    (items.series_id IS NULL OR items.date=MIN(series_table.date));
```

This seems to be inefficient. Doing it with a subquery in the WHERE clause also doesn't perform that well on my data set. Is there a better way to do this? I realize it might make sense to perform two queries with a UNION but unfortunately that's the one thing that the application executing this query would make difficult, so I'm hoping there's a better single-query approach.

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
    id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    title varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
    series_id int(10) DEFAULT NULL, 
    date datetime NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    KEY series_id (series_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO items (id, title, series_id, date)
   VALUES (1, 'Item 1 (no series)', NULL, '2019-12-01 00:00:00'),
          (2, 'Item 2 (no series)', NULL, '2019-12-02 00:00:00'),
          (3, 'Item 3 (series)', 1, '2019-12-03 00:00:00'),
          (4, 'Item 4 (series)', 1, '2019-12-04 00:00:00');
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: This may be a variant of "groupwise-max".

Comment: In looking at groupwise-max, it seems like the examples expect series_id to always have a value, whereas here some items are part of a series and some not. -- Would it make a significant difference in performance if there was always a value for series_id, even when it's not really a series, so that it could at least be an inner join instead of a left join?

Comment: Please provide the desired resultset.  That way, we can work backward to generate the desired result without the ambiguities of Engish where you describe the result.

Comment: Thanks. Desired result set is as the query above returns (Item 4 filtered out because Item 3 occurs earlier in the same series):

1 NULL Item 1 (no series) 2019-12-01 00:00:00
2 NULL Item 2 (no series) 2019-12-02 00:00:00
3 1 Item 3 (series) 2019-12-03 00:00:00